# make a foreign key nullable

Tags: sql

Is it possible with help of SQL to make foreign key to be nullable, even if primary doesn't allow NULL, and is IDENTITY? thanks.

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Yes, a FK column can allow null values.  What does this have to do with C#?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Yes FK column can have null values but it's not recommend

Comment: @Rahul: there is nothing wrong with making a FK nullable. "Not recommended" is an overly broad claim and I can think of many reasons when this _will_ make sense

Answer (score 1):

Of course a foreign key can be null-able.  This is recommended and the right thing to do in many cases.  In this case, the `NULL` value implies that there is no matching relationship.

For instance, if you have a hierarchy of employees with the manager as a foreign key relationship, then the person at the top has no manager -- and this could very well be represented as a `NULL` value.

You may want to be careful, depending on who your users are.  For instance, imagine that you have a `CountryId` for your customers but you don't know the country for some customers.  Users of your database might expect the `CountryId` to be valid and write queries such as:

```
select . . . 
from Customers cu join
     Countries co
     on cu.CountryId = co.CountryId;
```

This would inadvertently filter out customers with no customers.  To avoid the need for a `left join`, you can add a "default" or "unknown" country and require that the foreign key be non-`NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got your definitions mixed.

- A primary key must be a non-nullable, unique column (or a set of columns).
- An Identity is a property of a column, that simply makes your database issue an automatic value to a column. An Identity column can't be updated but it can be inserted with user-defined values, so it can have non-unique values.
- A foreign key is a relationship between two tables. This relationship links two tables by a column (or a set of columns).  A foreign key is either a one-to-one relationship or one-to-many relationship. When a column is on the many side of the foreign key it can be null.